# Circular reference error when serializing objects with custom Equals and GetHashCode methods

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, serialization, xml-serialization

I get **A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type T** error when returning my object as result of WebMethod of my asmx web service.

If I remove Equals and GetHashCode from class T problem disappears.
I don't have any circular references, so it looks like serialization detects circular references by comparing objects and if they are equal it thinks that there are circles.

Of course, I could define one class with Equals and another class for serialization, like many people do, and then copy data from one into another, but I want to be able to do it in one class to avoid [parallel class hierarchies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParallelClassHierarchies) as one of [code smells](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeSmell).

I want to be able to define Equals, GetHashCode and keep it [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx). How ?

Comment: OnSerializing and OnSerialized attributes could help to set flag and disable/enable methods behavior when serialization starts/ends, but it does not work for WebMethods result SOAP/Xml serializer.

Comment: can you give a small, simple example that illustrates the problem? Please include the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations that cause the problem.

Comment: Also, if you're using ASMX web services, then `[Serializable]` doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I am using one class to support both System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer and Xml WebMethod serialization. So far it worked until I defined Equals and GetHashCode to be able to place them in dictionary and merge dups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to inherit every class involved in serialization from one interface, which defines OnSerializing method and implement that method in every class to invoke it for eligible children. Also have Serializing private bool member in every class with false as default and set it to true inside OnSerializing. That will allow to call it on root and propagate to all serializable nodes till every leaf.

Call returnValue.OnSerializing() right before returning serialiable returnValue from WebMethod.

Every time you override Equals first line should be `if(Serializing)return base.Equals(obj);`, first line in GetHashCode should be `if(Serializing)return base.GetHashCode();`

That way right before returning from WebMethod by calling OnSerializing you mark whole tree to disable customization of Equals and GetHashCode.

If you need to do something after serialization (for example to save on disk and then return), then define OnSerialized and propagate through tree same way to set Serializing flag to false.

Of course, if possible, just inherit all serializable objects from one class instead of interface and implement everything there to reduce implementation overhead in every serializable class.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get down to the root of the trouble.
Because I had the same Problem.

I realized, that the problem is not found in the GetHashCode-method but rather in the Equals-method.

The most important reason why the XmlSerializer throws an exception of that kind is because of the structure of a XML-document and the "equality mechanism" inside of the XmlSerializer.

For example:

```
private XmlSerializer serializer;

public void TryToSerialize(TextWriter output)
{
    MyObject instance = new MyObject();
    instance.Key = 101;
    instance.SomeValue = "Some value";
    instance.Child = new MyObject();
    instance.Child.Key = 101;
    instance.Child.SomeValue = "Another value";

    serializer.Serialize(output, instance);
}
```

And how I implemented the GetHashCode-method and the Equals-method?

Like this:

```
public overrides int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Key.GetHashCode();
}

public overrides bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null) return false;

    MyObject other = obj as MyObject;
    if(other == null) return false;

    return this.Key.Equals(other.Key);
}
```

And what would happen, if I run the "TryToSerialize"-method?
I will get an **InvalidOperationException** with the message *A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type T*.

On serilization, the XmlSerializer tries to avoid adding the same object as a child to the XML-document, because this will cause to a circle.
But the way to check "is this the same object" is to use the GetHashCode-method and the Equals-method for what they are designed to - to check the equality of objects.

In our example, these objects migth be different instances, and the XmlSerializer do not check for "instances in memory", but use the methods it knows - GetHashCode and Equals.

So, think about how you implement your **Equals-method**

Or better...

Think how you can improve the implementation of your classes and methods to avoid this problem at *the root of the trouble*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case,i resolved implementing (automatic visual studio code completation)  correctly methods Equals and GetHashCode, like that:

```
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var permission = obj as Permission;
            return permission != null &&
                   EqualityComparer<AccessLevel>.Default.Equals(Access, permission.Access) &&
                   EqualityComparer<Functionality>.Default.Equals(Function, permission.Function);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = -720887508;
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<AccessLevel>.Default.GetHashCode(Access);
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<Functionality>.Default.GetHashCode(Function);
            return hashCode;
        }
```

previous code was only Equals method and like that:

```
return (Access.Name.Equals((Permission)obj.Name)...
```